# Tab Layout appear blank fragment view and disappear after tab change

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-tablayout

I am using Tablayout without viewpager as per my requirement and want to use multiple tabs. Here My app working fine for the very first time or after tapping last few fragments make it blank and i can see the view back if i make it minimize to maximize or unlock device or close the app and restart is option. Thanks in advance.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/header"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabGravity="fill" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/header"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />


</LinearLayout>
```

and my code:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try {
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.trans_left_in, R.anim.trans_left_out);
            setContentView(R.layout.app_bar_main);
            activityComponent().inject(this);
            instance = this;
            toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            toolbar.setTitle("" + EPreference.getInstance().getStringValue(EPreference.EVENTNAME));
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
            tabViewGroup = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.content_main);

            tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
            tabLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mMainPresenter.attachView(this);
            if (!EApplication.get().isLaoggedin) {
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
                progressDialog.setProgress(0);
                progressDialog.show();
                mMainPresenter.syncAllDataAtOnce();

            }


            bindWidgetsWithAnEvent();
            tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
            try {
                if (tabLayout.getTabCount() > 0)
                    tabLayout.removeAllTabs();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.demo_tab_1)), true);
            tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.demo_tab_3)));
            tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.demo_tab_2)));
            tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.demo_tab_4)));
            tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.demo_tab_5)));
            tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.demo_tab_6)));
            tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.demo_tab_7)));
            tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.demo_tab_9)));
            tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.demo_tab_8)));
            tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.demo_tab_10)));
            tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.demo_tab_11)));
            tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.demo_tab_12)));
            tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.demo_tab_13)));
            tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.demo_tab_14)));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void bindWidgetsWithAnEvent() {
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                setCurrentTabFragment(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            }
        });
    }



    private void setCurrentTabFragment(int tabPosition) {
        String type = "";
        String sender_id = "";
        String wallStr = "false", guestStr = "false", chatStr = "false", OneToOne = "true";
        try {
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            if (extras != null) {
                type = extras.getString("type");
                if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("Wall")) {
                    wallStr = "true";
                } else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("Guest")) {
                    guestStr = "true";
                } else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("Chat")) {
                    sender_id = extras.getString("other");
                    OneToOne = extras.getString("OneToOne");
                    chatStr = sender_id;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        switch (tabPosition) {
            case 0:
                WallFragment wallFragment = WallFragment.newInstance();
                bundle.putString("page_source", wallStr);
                wallFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                replaceFragment(wallFragment);
                break;

            case 1:
                EventFragment eventFragment = EventFragment.newInstance();
                replaceFragment(eventFragment);
                break;

            case 2:
                GuestFragment guestFragment = GuestFragment.newInstance();
                bundle.putString("page_source", guestStr);
                guestFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                replaceFragment(guestFragment);
                break;
            case 3:
                GallleryGridFragment gallleryGridFragment = GallleryGridFragment.newInstance();
                replaceFragment(gallleryGridFragment);
                break;
            case 4:
                ChatFragment chatFragment = ChatFragment.newInstance();
                bundle.putString("page_source", chatStr);
                bundle.putString("OneToOne", OneToOne);
                chatFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                replaceFragment(chatFragment);
                break;
            case 5:
                GiftFragment giftFragment = GiftFragment.newInstance();
                replaceFragment(giftFragment);
                break;
            case 6:
                FeedbackFragment feedbackFragment = FeedbackFragment.newInstance();
                replaceFragment(feedbackFragment);
                break;
            case 7:
                ExpenseFragment expenseFragment = ExpenseFragment.newInstance();
                replaceFragment(expenseFragment);
                break;
            case 8:
                HotelRoomFragment hotelRoomFragment = HotelRoomFragment.newInstance();
                replaceFragment(hotelRoomFragment);
                break;
            case 9:
                replaceFragment(VendorFragment.newInstance());
                break;
            case 10:
                replaceFragment(ParticularFragment.newInstance());
                break;
            case 11:
                replaceFragment(ProfileFragment.newInstance());
                break;
            case 12:
                replaceFragment(BroadcastFragment.newInstance());
                break;
            case 13:
                replaceFragment(NearByFragment.newInstance());
                break;

        }
    }

    public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_main, fragment);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        ft.commit();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
Activity class

```
 TabLayout tabLayout;
int values;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try {

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        bindWidgetsWithAnEvent();
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
        try {
            if (tabLayout.getTabCount() > 0)
                tabLayout.removeAllTabs();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        values=1;
        openFragment(Event_Fragment.class);

        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("1"), true);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("2"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("3"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("4"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("5"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("6"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("7"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("8"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("9"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("10"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("11"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("12"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("13"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("14"));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void bindWidgetsWithAnEvent() {
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            setCurrentTabFragment(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }
    });
}



private void setCurrentTabFragment(int tabPosition) {
    String type = "";
    String sender_id = "";
    String wallStr = "false", guestStr = "false", chatStr = "false", OneToOne = "true";
    try {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            type = extras.getString("type");
            if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("Wall")) {
                wallStr = "true";
            } else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("Guest")) {
                guestStr = "true";
            } else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("Chat")) {
                sender_id = extras.getString("other");
                OneToOne = extras.getString("OneToOne");
                chatStr = sender_id;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    switch (tabPosition) {
        case 0:
            values=1;
            openFragment(Event_Fragment.class);
           /* Event_Fragment wallFragment = Event_Fragment.newInstance();
            bundle.putString("page_source", wallStr);
            wallFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            replaceFragment(wallFragment);*/
            break;

        case 1:
            values=2;
            openFragment(Event_Fragment.class);
            break;

        case 2:
            values=3;
            openFragment(Event_Fragment.class);
            break;
        case 3:
            values=4;
            openFragment(Event_Fragment.class);
            break;
        case 4:
            values=5;
            openFragment(Event_Fragment.class);
            break;
        case 5:
            values=6;
            openFragment(Event_Fragment.class);
            break;
        case 6:
            values=7;
            openFragment(Event_Fragment.class);
            break;
        case 7:
            values=8;
            openFragment(Event_Fragment.class);
            break;
        case 8:
            values=9;
            openFragment(Event_Fragment.class);
            break;
        case 9:
            values=10;
            openFragment(Event_Fragment.class);
            break;
        case 10:
            values=11;
            openFragment(Event_Fragment.class);
            break;
        case 11:
            values=12;
            openFragment(Event_Fragment.class);
            break;
        case 12:
            values=13;
            openFragment(Event_Fragment.class);
            break;
        case 13:
            values=14;
            openFragment(Event_Fragment.class);
            break;

    }
}
  public void openFragment(Class fragmentClass) {
    try {
        Fragment fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("values", values);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content, fragment, fragmentClass.getSimpleName()).commit();
      //  setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="Tab event"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabGravity="fill" />

</LinearLayout>
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">

</FrameLayout>
```

Fragment XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="Tab event"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks but issue is remain same. Not working for me.

Comment: Use <FrameLayout/>

Comment: where i am using  <include layout="@layout/content_main" /> is going on the page where using <FrameLayout/>

Comment: But its not replace all time so use in main xml.

Comment: In random way its showing blank, Sometime it works fine but sometime not.